# Memory usage with high precision

Tags: linux, memory, ps

How can I get high precision memory usage per proccess with "ps aux"?

```
$ ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0   3672  1984 ?        Ss   Dec11   0:07 /sbin/init
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec11   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec11   0:23 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         6  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec11   0:00 [migration/0]
...
```

I need more than 1 digit after point.
Maybe I can format column with %MEM?

Answer (score 2):

Look into the proc filesystem `/proc/[pid]/status`, `/proc/[pid]/statm`, `/proc/[pid]/smaps`.

To get fully detailed memory map `/proc/[pid]/maps`

Read the [proc(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) manual page for all the details.

Comment: For process 1234, look into `/proc/1234/`, for your own process, look into `/proc/self/` (e.g. `/proc/1234/maps` or `/proc/self/maps`) And `/proc/meminfo` tells about the entire system.

Answer (score 0):

the **`ps`** command have that. you can type **`man ps`** for detail.

when the termianl show info after you typed it, you can type **`/memory`** , then heighlight contain `'memory'`'s string. you can type `n` show next palace with `memory`.